# XLSXWriter refuses to create a second Excel File

Tags: python, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I'm working on a program to split excel files into sections of 1000. I can't seem to get it to create a second excel file, as xlsxwriter doesn't create the second file.

```
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
from xlrd.sheet import ctype_text
import csv
import os
import sys
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import xlwt

file_paths = sys.argv[1:]
draganddrop = ''.join(file_paths)
beginGrab = 0
counting = 0
endGrab = 1000    
thousands = 0

if draganddrop == "":
    fileName = raw_input("\nInput the file with extension\n>")      
else:
    fileName = draganddrop

stopPoint = fileName.index('.')
prepRev = fileName[stopPoint:]
preName = fileName[:stopPoint]

if prepRev == ".csv":
    excelFile = xlsxwriter.Workbook(preName + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = excelFile.add_worksheet()
    with open(fileName,'rb') as f:
        content = csv.reader(f)
        for index_col, data_in_col in enumerate(content):
            for index_row, data_in_cell in enumerate(data_in_col):
                worksheet.write(index_col,index_row,data_in_cell)
    excelFile.close()
    fileName = (preName + '.xlsx')
    delMe = 1
    print("Temporary Convert to xlsx done.\n")

stopPoint = fileName.index('.')
prepRev = fileName[0:stopPoint]   
fname = join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), fileName)
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
worksheet = book.add_sheet("Results", cell_overwrite_ok=True)

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName)
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = int(row)

if(int(row)>1000):
    subDivide = int(row) / 1000
    while(thousands != subDivide + 1):
        thousands = thousands + 1  
        counting = 0
        totalName = preName + "_" + str(thousands) + ".xlsx"
        print(totalName)
        excelFile = xlsxwriter.Workbook(str(totalName))
        worksheet = excelFile.add_worksheet()
        with open(totalName,'rb') as f:
            col = xl_sheet.col_slice(0,1,10101010)
            for idx, cell_obj in enumerate(col, start=beginGrab):
                counting = counting + 1
                if(counting == 1000):
                    break                   
                cell_type_str = ctype_text.get(cell_obj.ctype, 'unknown type')  
                cell_obj_str = str(cell_obj)
                telePhone = (cell_obj_str[7:19])
                worksheet.write(idx+1, 0, "1" + telePhone)          
        worksheet.write(0,0, "Telephone Number")
        beginGrab = thousands * 1000
        endGrab = beginGrab + 1000
        excelFile.close()
        excelFile = None

else:
    print("Mate, this is Tiny!")
print ("Ding! Job Done!")
```

I've been rubber ducking this and I can't find where I'm at fault.

EDIT:

SOLVED!!

By creating a sheet and then closing it, the program can then grasp it. I will probably make a git issue about this.

```
if prepRev == ".csv":
    totalName = preName + '.xlsx'
    excelFile = xlsxwriter.Workbook(totalName)
    excelFile.close()
```

Closing it lets open see it while it still contains the same info.

```
    excelFile = xlsxwriter.Workbook(totalName)
    worksheet = excelFile.add_worksheet()
    with open(fileName,'rb') as f:
```

Comment: can you post a traceback of the error you're getting? (I've answered, but I'm not sure it's the only problem you've got)

Comment: `File "/home/nmenard/Documents/Haircuttery/FileSplit.py", line 62, in <module>`
`with open(totalName,'rb') as f:`
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'OyVey_2.xlsx'`

Is this right?

Comment: @GarnetSunset what if you use the full path, such as `/my/file/OyVey_2.xlsx`. Are you sure that file is there and exists (with the _2 extension??)

Comment: @David542 The issue seems to be that xlsxwriter doesn't CREATE the file. Not that it can't be found.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the `save/close` line need to be within the while loop? Otherwise it looks like it will only save either the first/last item:

```
while(thousands != subDivide + 1):
    # write file
    excelFile.close()
```

Comment: I moved it back, and I'm STILL seeing the same error. Let me edit my code in the main to add your fix.

Answer (score 1):

that line is probably the reason why you cannot read back your file and your script crashes:

```
fname = join(dirname(abspath('__file__')), '%s' % fileName)
```

`'__file__'` shouldn't have quotes. I'd do:

```
fname = join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), fileName)
```

Comment: Very nice addition, thank you, but, for some reason this still didn't work.